# To Deserialize JSON and return the Value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin, serialization

I'm working on Xamarin App, where I'm trying to get the Json data from the server, and it's working fine.

But, now I just want to read/view the value of **"invitation"**.

**Json Value:**

```
{"invitation":"http://example.com?c_i=eyJsYWJlbCI6Iklzc3VlciIsImltYWdlVXJsIjpudWxsLCJzZXJ2aWNlRW5kcG9pbnQiOiJodHRwOi8vNTIuNzcuMjI4LjIzNDo3MDAwIiwicm91dGluZ0tleXMiOlsiSE51N0x6MkxoZktONEZEMzM2cWdDNWticWI0dTZWRkt2NERaano4YWc1eHQiXSwicmVjaXBpZW50S2V5cyI6WyI3Sm1MMVhOSHRqSHB2WW1KS3d0ZXM2djltNk5yVUJoZW1ON3J6TnZLcGN0SyJdLCJAaWQiOiIzZjgyNWRkZC0zNjNhLTQ2YzEtYTAxNi0xMjAwY2FhZjRkNTkiLCJAdHlwZSI6ImRpZDpzb3Y6QnpDYnNOWWhNcmpIaXFaRFRVQVNIZztzcGVjL2Nvbm5lY3Rpb25zLzEuMC9pbnZpdGF0aW9uIn0="}
```

I'm getting  this error... don't know why?

**Error Message:**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Index.IndexViewModel+RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'invitation', line 1, position 14.'
```

The
Code I wrote.....

**Class:**

```
public class ConnectionJson
{
    public string Invitation { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ConnectionJson> ConnectionsJson { get; set; }
}
```

**Main Code :**

```
   public async Task<List<RootObject>> ConnectionInvitationJson()
        {
            HttpClient hTTPClient = new HttpClient();

            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://example.com/Connections/CreateInvitationJson"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await hTTPClient.GetAsync(uri);

            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(content);

            await DialogService.AlertAsync(Items.ToString(), "Connection Invitation Json", "Ok");

            return Items;
        }
```

Comment: Why so many `List<>`s when the JSON doesn't have any arrays?

Comment: what is the need of `.ToString()` in this line `await DialogService.AlertAsync(Items.ToString(), "Connection Invitation Json", "Ok");`?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty to output the json value in dialogue box.

Comment: `.ToString()` will not give you the JSON value, instead use this `await DialogService.AlertAsync(content, "Connection Invitation Json", "Ok");`

Comment: but it returns the complete json... I just want the value of 'invitation'...

Comment: `await DialogService.AlertAsync(json.Invitation, "Connection Invitation Json", "Ok");` update to this

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty this helps.... THANKS ALOT... Man, u saved my time... thanks :)

Comment: @JoeDoe, Glad that I was helpful

Comment: sorry, I tried it earlier but didn't work... anyways ... thanks thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json is just a single object. Update the code as below

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConnectionJson>(content);
```

After updating the code you can modify the logic as below if you don't want to change the classes structure

```
var Items = new List<RootObject> { new List<ConnectionJson> { json }};
```

Comment: no error but in dialogue box the msg is ```"Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Index.IndexViewModel+ConnectionJson'```

Comment: added a comment for that to the question. please check

Comment: @JoeDoe, I have no idea about xamarin. Sorry, I could not help you on this